# LuaLaTeX, with TeX Live 2022 and fourier-otf, fails to superscript en-dashes

Tags: fonts, superscripts, fourier-otf

After updating to TeX Live 2022, I am unable to produce superscript en-dashes, with `fourier-otf`. `\textsuperscript{1--3}`, simply produces superscript numerals, with a non-superscript, regular en-dash, between them.

I am using LuaLaTeX. Here is a MWE (with thanks to [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe), for considerable assistance getting to this stage):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier-otf}

\begin{document}
    
    A\textsuperscript{1--3}

\end{document}
```

Switching back to TeX Live 2021 fixes this issue. I cannot find any other side-effects.

Does anyone know what might be going on here and how to resolve this (or workaround it, until a patch is produced)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The newest version of fourier-otf loads the realscripts package. This gives nicer looking superscripts at the cost that it doesn't work for all letters and symbols. You can access the standard superscript command with a starred version (or with `\fakesuperscript`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier-otf}

\begin{document}
    
    A\textsuperscript{1--3} A\textsuperscript*{1--3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can disable the loading of the realscripts package with

```
\makeatletter \disable@package@load{realscripts}{}\makeatother
```

Then naturally the starred versions and the fake commands won't work anymore.